# Two column layout with min-width on left column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a two column layout like this:

```
<style>.less-padding{ padding: 0 5px; }</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="less-padding col-xs-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">foo</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit ...
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="less-padding col-xs-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">bar</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit ...
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want the left column to stay at a min-width of `250px` when the user resizes the browser and the right one to use up the remaining space.
So I tried something like this:

```
<div class="less-padding col-xs-4" style="min-width:250px">
```

It works, but the right column will now break under the left as I resize my browser due to Bootstrap's percentaged column widths.

Is there a way to prevent this and make it use the remaining space instead?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym7srqhd/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a media query to define the point where the first column is 250px and make some CSS changes.

For example, this is how I did it:

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nL7L25fL)

Comment: This could work. I'll try it. But please edit your CSS Code into your answer and make the URL a clickable link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this using Bootstrap "out-of-the-box", but you can use CSS3's flexbox along with Bootstrap..

http://bootply.com/3fZNoWqbTu

Comment: This is a nice solution. But unfortunately I have to support Internet Explorer 9 and older where flexbox is not supportet.